# Why isn't the confirmation appearing before destroying record?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Ruby on Rails I'm trying to get a confirmation message to appear before the record is destroyed.

My application.html.erb file has:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`
```

The application.js file has:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

This is the code in the index.html.erb file for the button

```
<%= button_to "Delete", admin_country, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

This is the destroy function from the Controller:

```
def destroy
  @admin_country = Admin::Country.find(params[:id])
  @admin_country.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to admin_countries_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Why isn't the confirmation message appearing? It deletes the record fine, it doesn't show the confirmation box though which I really would like it to.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Rails are you using?

confirm: "message" is deprecated in Rails 4.

Use:

```
<%= button_to "Delete", admin_country, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :delete %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this

```
<%= button_to "Delete", { action: "admin_country" },
                                method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that I'm getting a routing problem, what do you mean by action: "admin_country"?